# Milnor's proof that a smooth manifold has the homotopy type of a CW complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes, morse-theory

I have some questions about the proof of Theorem 3.5 of Milnor’s “Morse Theory”:
[image]
At the end of the proof of this theorem, Milnor addresses the case when $f$ has infinitely many critical points:
[image]
Questions:

1. Is the limit map $g$ the colimit of the graphs of the maps $g_i : M^{a_i} \to K_i$?, i.e. $\textrm{Graph}(g_i) = \{(g_i(m), m) : m \in M^{a_i}\}$ (as each map extends the previous one, the colimit of the graphs (i.e. a colimit of sets) makes sense.)
2. Why does $g$ induce isomorphisms of homotopy groups in all dimensions?
3. Why does $M$ being a retract of its tubular neighbourhood in a euclidean space mean it is dominated by a CW complex? (Hatcher, Proposition A.11 p. 528. has an elementary proof that "A space dominated by a CW complex is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex.", so if it is obvious that $M$ is dominated by a CW complex, why was Morse theory even needed to prove Theorem 3.5?)

Google books has the section available to view (p23-24) https://books.google.com.au/books?id=A9QZZ3S_QxwC&lpg=PA25&pg=PA23#v=onepage&q&f=false

Thank you.

Comment: On 1 and 2, yes "limit" is old-school terminology for "colimit". Under nice assumptions, the colimit of a sequence of homotopy equivalences is a weak equivalence, see for example: lemma on p. 67 of May https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf

Comment: Maybe the important point of the Morse theory is not that the space has the homotopy type of a CW complex, but that you can get its cell structure from Morse theory.

Comment: Ok, on 3, I am convinced that Milnor is hiding some gory details. I have not found a reasonable proof that the tubular neighborhood gives a dominating CW-complex. Every standard reference I could find deals only with the case that $M$ is compact. In this case, 3 is trivial. There are some technical proofs out there that an ENR is dominated by a CW-complex (old 40s stuff). There are also methods of triangulation of smooth manifolds. I really don't know what Milnor had in mind specifically, but, I think you'll have to dig into the literature to get a full answer.

Comment: A starting point would be Milnor, On spaces having the homotopy type of a CW-complex. In there, you'll see that he dodges exactly the issue raised by 3. The reference he gives is: O. Hanner, Some theorems on absolute neighborhood retracts, Ark. Mat. vol. 1 (1950) pp.389-408.

Comment: @JustinYoung Thanks a lot for your comments and for tracking down that reference. If you post it as an answer I will accept it... but bounty ends in 1 hour!

Comment: @JustinYoung can you also clarify how May's lemma answers 2? I see that this lemma gives $$\pi_n(M) \simeq \operatorname{colim}_i \pi_n(M^{a_i}) \simeq  \operatorname{colim}_i \pi_n(X_i) \simeq \pi_n(X) ,$$ but it is not enough for Whitehead's theorem that the groups are isomorphic in all dimensions: the isomorphism has to be induced by $g$. I think this is really simple but I can't  seem to express why $g$ is inducing the isomorphism. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting comments as an answer, response to question in comments below.

On 1 and 2, yes "limit" is old-school terminology for "colimit". Under nice assumptions, the colimit of a sequence of homotopy equivalences is a weak equivalence, see for example: lemma on p. 67 of May math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf

On the parenthetical comment in 3: the important point of the Morse theory is not that the space has the homotopy type of a CW complex, but that you can get its cell structure from Morse theory.

On 3: I am convinced that Milnor is hiding some gory details. I have not found a reasonable proof that the tubular neighborhood gives a dominating CW-complex. Every standard reference I could find deals only with the case that M is compact. In this case, 3 is trivial. There are some technical proofs out there that an ENR is dominated by a CW-complex (old 40s stuff). There are also methods of triangulation of smooth manifolds. I really don't know what Milnor had in mind specifically, but, I think you'll have to dig into the literature to get a full answer. A starting point would be Milnor, On spaces having the homotopy type of a CW-complex. In there, you'll see that he dodges exactly the issue raised by 3. The reference he gives is: O. Hanner, Some theorems on absolute neighborhood retracts, Ark. Mat. vol. 1 (1950) pp.389-408.

Finally, if we look at May's Lemma, first of all it should be clear that the isomorphism $\text{colim } \pi_n(X_i) \cong \pi_n(X)$ is not just any old isomorphism, but it is induced by the maps $X_i\to X$. Now, if we follow your chain of isomorphisms above, you see that the isomorphism $\text{colim } \pi_n(M^{a_i}) \cong \text{colim } \pi_n(K_i)$ is induced by the maps $M^{a_i} \to K_i$. Since the map $M\to K$ is the colimit map (see above), it is induced by $M^{a_i}\to K_i$, and therefore the isomorphism $\pi_n(M) \cong \text{colim } \pi_n(M^{a_i}) \cong \text{colim } \pi_n(K_i) \cong \pi_n(K)$ is induced by the colimit map $M\to K$.

Comment: The answer below  (of Mathy) shows that the tubular neighborhood is a (countable) cell complex, and by general homotopy theory, this is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex. This answers $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Ad 3) $M$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^N$ for $N \in \mathbb{N}$ by Whitney. Then, a tubular neighbourhood of $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$. And open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^N$ are CW-complexes (choose a grid of edge length $1/n$ to fill the open set up). Therefore $M$ is dominated by a CW-complex per definitionem. Finally, as you mentioned A.11 in Hatcher and Whitehead's theorem complete the proof.

Comment: This works well if $M$ is compact, but if $M$ is not compact the tube might have arbitrarily small diameter, and then $1/n$ is too big to "fill the open set up". Could you elaborate how this works with details?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but by the following argument you can see that any open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a CW-complex:
The idea is to create a grid of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of grid-edge-lengths all equal to $1/n$ and vertices therefore all rational. Then you take those boxes of the grid, which lie completely in $U$. Do that for all $n$ and you covered $U$ completely with boxes of rational edge lengths and rational vertices, so that there are only countably many (do we need countability for CW-complexes?). This gives $U$ the structure of a CW-complex (each box is a $D^n$).

Comment: Ok, I'm convinced you have some kind of cell complex there, to get a true CW structure requires some work, unless you can tell me precisely what are the cells and how do the attachments work?

Comment: @Mathy thanks for your comments. Do you know of a written reference for the claim that every open subset of $R^n$ is a CW complex? It does sound plausible but I'd like to see some more details as well. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any reference either.
@Justin: I can tell you that precisely. Once you've covered your whole open subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ up with those boxes (and we can even forget about the rationality arguments, because a CW-complex can also have uncountably many cells), you take the grid points as the 0-skeleton $U_0$. Then for every box, your attaching map $S^n \to U_0$ is given through connecting the corresponding grid points of the box via straight lines (one can use the homeomorphism $S^n \to \partial I^n$).

Comment: The zero skeleton is discrete so your attaching maps will have to all be constant. That can't be what you have in mind.

Comment: Ohh, yeah. Right. Let's just examine this for $n=2$. Your $0$-skeleton $U_0$ is the (discrete) set of grid points. First, we will glue in the edges, to get a grid, $U_1$, the $1$-skeleton. Then, we glue in the surfaces to get $U_2 = U$. This works for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$: First the vertices of the grid ($\leadsto U_0$). Then the edges ($\leadsto U_1$), then the surfaces ($\leadsto U_2$, ... This is just the natural CW-complex structure of a $n$-grid in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I still think that is a bit vague, but clearly it's obvious to you. I think you can make a compactness argument to say that each box intersects finitely many other boxes, that might help to clear up the chaos. But these attachments can look crazy, and I think you need some argument to clarify why this fits together so nicely. Alternatively, you could use the fact that a cell complex is homotopy equivalent to a CW-complex, that would recover the result in the OP.

Comment: What do you mean by "...fits together so nicely"? Maybe I am just overseeing something and might be wrong. By the way, also, $U = \cup_i U_i$ then has the colimit topology, as those boxes generate the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Ok, maybe this will clarify, if you take the set of grid points for all $n$, you have a dense set of points. So all the grid points can't be the 0-skeleton, just the grid points on the corners of some box. Now, when do you attach 2 grid points with an edge? When it is the edge of some box? No, that would be redundant, as some larger boxes will have vertices not on the corners, thus you attach them if they are the corners of a box that doesn't share an edge with a smaller box. This should be possible by compactness. I think you can go from here, but it is complicated as you go up the dimensions

Comment: I don't get it. The set of grid points surely isn't dense, but there might be accumulation points. But what's wrong with that?

Comment: Well, at the least, you can't have accumulation points in the 0-skeleton of a CW complex. Yes, the set of all grid points for all $n$ is definitely dense (this $n$ refers to the size $1/n$ of the edges of the boxes). Obviously you don't take all the grid points, just the ones on a box that you choose inside the open set.  I'm not sure how much more specific I can be, so I'll let it drop here.

Comment: Okay, you're right, I can't have accumulation points in the 0-sceleton, since the sceletons have to be closed.